# How to use `tf.gradients`? `TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>`

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, gradient

I am getting this error: `TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>`

I want to calculate the gradient of the `loss` w.r.t. `m_leftops2`:

```
t_im0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, None], name='left_img')
t_im1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, None], name='right_img')

strides=[1,1,1,1]
m_leftOps2 =  tf.tanh(tf.nn.conv2d(t_im0, w1, strides=strides, padding=padding, data_format="NCHW")+b)
m_rightOps2 = tf.tanh(tf.nn.conv2d(t_im1, w1, strides=strides, padding=padding, data_format="NCHW")+b)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(m_leftOps2 * m_rightOps2)
t_gradients = tf.gradients(xs=loss, ys=[m_leftOps2])

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    feed_dict = {t_im0: normalized_i1, t_im1: normalized_i2}
    print("gradients: ", sess.run([loss, t_gradients], feed_dict=feed_dict))
```

If I calculate the gradient of `m_leftOps2`, I should get as result `m_rightOps2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) calculates the derivative of ***ys*** with respect to ***xs***. So you have your arguments backwards. Try this:

```
t_gradients = tf.gradients( ys = loss, xs = m_leftOps2 )
```